# Cannot pull photos from iPhone5 to Fedora 26

Tags: fedora, usb-drive, iphone

I'm trying to get photos off an iPhone 5 into a PC running Fedora 26, but all I am getting is messages about `cannot claim USB device` or `unable to fetch previews`.

Does anyone know what I need to do?

`lsusb` is reporting:

```
Bus 003 Device 017: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
```

`dmesg` is saying:

```
[30641.713861] usb 3-9: new high-speed USB device number 16 using xhci_hcd

[30641.883473] usb 3-9: New USB device found, idVendor=05ac, idProduct=12a8

[30641.883475] usb 3-9: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3

[30641.883476] usb 3-9: Product: iPhone

[30641.883476] usb 3-9: Manufacturer: Apple Inc.

[30641.883477] usb 3-9: SerialNumber: a8b66fed19c9af4b47192c38f02381b0c33a56ad

[30641.922552] ipheth 3-9:4.2: Apple iPhone USB Ethernet device attached

[30641.940212] ipheth 3-9:4.2 enp0s20u9c4i2: renamed from eth0

[30641.954568] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp0s20u9c4i2: link is not ready

[30647.328964] ipheth 3-9:4.2: ipheth_tx_timeout: TX timeout
```

Also, I have tried idevicepair, but all I got was

> No device found, is it plugged in?

I have also replaced the USB cable, with no change.

Comment: Not a solution to the actual problem (which might be a missing gvfs module), but I use Syncthing to sync files from my phone to computer. It skips the hassle of connecting via USB and having troubles like yours. Find it at https://syncthing.net/ with instructions how to install for Fedora via COPR.

Answer (score 0):

Your iPhone is acting as a network device when you plug it in.

You need to tell it to act as a block device/external drive instead.

Refer to your iPhone documentation on how to do that.